# enter-pssession not working over Wireguard

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, winrm

I have multiple computers in a LAN and a Windows Server 2012 R2 in another city. They are all in a Wireguard VPN. I can use SMB file shares, PSexec, RDP and such things, but can't make WinRM enter-pssession work because

> enter-pssession : Connecting to remote server myserver failed with the
> following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.
> If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the
> client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must
> be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
> configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note
> that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

It says I either needs to set https OR have the trusted hosts set, so I chose the latter, but it still doesn't work even when Windows Firewall is off.
winrm quickconfig has been done, trusted hosts contain the whole Wireguard IP subnet

```
get-item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts
Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   192.168.200.*
```

winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener shows it's listening on the Wireguard NIC ip.
test-wsman command works both ways, so why not enter-pssession?